# Nested horizontal RecyclerView within a vertical RecyclerView with dynamically sized elements not measuring size correctly

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I have a vertical list of sections and each section has a horizontal list of items.

Each item width in the nested list should correspond to the text which is dynamically insrted to it.

90% of the items show with the appropriate size but some 10% show with too much width or too little, cutting off the text.

How can we solve the issue? Or otherwise how to implement nested `RecyclerView` correctly?

This is the layout file for the nested `RecyclerView` item. It uses `wrap_content` width for the parent and `match_parent` width for the children to make the width correspond to the widest child element:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="73dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="29dp"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="52dp" />

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

This is how I initialize the nested `RecyclerView`. It is called from `onBindViewHolder` of the parent (vertical) `RecyclerView` adapter class:

```
RecyclerView nestedRecyclerView = holder.view
    .findViewById(R.id.tasks_expansion)
    .findViewById(R.id.rv_expansion_tasks);
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(
    nestedRecyclerView.getContext(),
    LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,
    true
);
            

layoutManager.setInitialPrefetchItemCount(menuItem.getContentBoxes().size());
RecyclerViewAdapterContentBoxes nestedAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapterContentBoxes(
    nestedRecyclerView.getContext(),
    menuItem.getContentBoxes()
);
nestedRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
nestedRecyclerView.setAdapter(nestedAdapter);
nestedRecyclerView.setRecycledViewPool(viewPool);
```

I thought there might be a problem because of using a `RecyclerView` within a `RecylerView` but on the other hand this seems like a relatively common feature to have in your app. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to avoid the parent `wrap_content` and children `match_parent` trick to set the width as the max width of the children. Instead I set the width of parent and all children to `wrap_content` and added a clone of the second and third `TextView`s in the same place and same fill color as the first `TextView` but with the children's `textSize`, and also made their text transparent (by making the `textColor` same as the background). In the `RecyclerView`'s `onBindViewHolder` I added the corresponding duplicated texts. Also adding `layout_gravity` as `center_horizontal` to all three original `TextView`s to make it center (`gravity="center"` wouldn't be enough) . This resulted in all views measured correctly in the nested `RecyclerView`.